# Login info fails every time I open Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, msdn

I get this every time I open Visual Studio 2013/2015 (premium):

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

I can simply renter my credentials and everything works.  But why do I have to do it every time?

Comment: this might be helpful http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2892152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away and I don't know why (Windows update?) I did not have the preview version installed at any point, so that was not the solution for me, although it probably is for others.

Answer (score 9):

This problem occurs because the Visual Studio 2013 token cache is changing, and the cache is incompatible with the preview versions of Visual Studio 2013. To refresh the token, you have to reauthenticate. Check the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2892152 for more information.

Comment: Welcome to tha StackOverflow Community. You might want to know, that the Community Netiquette prefers [Answers] to contain the advices and there are strong efforts in place to avoid just-a-link sort of answers. You might face a penalty from moderators, who try to enforce this and similar policies, so you might want to rather re-read StackOverflow rules and re-edit your post so as to meet the Netiquette rules rather than to get any negative feedbacks in your future.

Comment: Yep, stackoverflowers like answers to be actually within the answer section due to 'link rot'; i.e., links break over time, for instance, if Microsoft change the URLs on their support website.

Comment: I had the same problem in VS2015. The solution was to Sign Out and then Sign In :)

Comment: Still the same error with VS 2015. 
Followed the instructions on Microsoft support site (sign out -> sign in) (for VS 2013) and I still got the same error.